# Crate a custom format category

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, in the `Format Cells` dialog, the `Number` tab, there are several number format categories to choose from.

Can I create my own category (eg. "SI units") to keep all my custom formats organized in one place?

Answer (score 2):

While it is not possible to create your own tab in the formatting dialog, you can save a cell that uses a custom format as a style. You can create many different styles and quickly apply them by opening the Styles panel on the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Excel doesn't support this.